# Node running in Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java

I can run the following command from the terminal in Windows:

```
D:\myProject> node ./node_modules/someModule/create.js -c control -b 1
```

But not if I try to run this within `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray, envp, dir)`.

```
String[] cmdarray = {"node", "./node_modules/someModule/create.js"};
String[] envp     = {"-c=control", "-b=1"};
File startingPath = new File("D:\myProject");

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray, envp, startingPath);
```

I also tried to the cmdarray as a single entry and even adding the arguments at the end and leaving envp empty.
But it's not working.

How would be the correct way to write the command? And is there a difference, when I run this on Windows and Mac?

Comment: I'd also consider `ProcessBuilder` as it provides more configuration options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put command line options into the environment. They are not environment variables! Put them into the command array ... as individual array elements; e.g.

```
String[] cmdarray = {
            "node", "./node_modules/someModule/create.js", 
            "-c", "control", "-b", "1"};
```

> And is there a difference, when I run this on Windows and Mac?

If you do it this way, there *should be* no difference between Windows and Mac.  But obviously it is up to you to test your code on all platforms you intend to support!

Note also that when you use a simple command name (e.g. `node`) the command needs to be on command search path; i.e. `$PATH` or `%PATH%`.